# Unproxy property mapping nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, proxy, nhibernate-mapping

you can put a property without a proxy? because I need to get the value of it. Below is the mapping:

```
  public class MateriaPrimaMap : ClassMap<MateriaPrima> {

    #region Construtor

    public MateriaPrimaMap() {
        Table("MATERIAPRIMA");           

        Id(m => m.Id).Column("MPR_CD");

        Map(m => m.Descricao)
        .Column("MPR_DS")
        .Not.Nullable().Length(30);

        Map(m => m.Ativo)
         .Column("MPR_ATIVO")
         .Not.Nullable();

        Version(m => m.Version).Column("MPR_DT_LK").Generated.Always();
    }

    #endregion
}}
```

image proxy proprety:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean by value the instance, id or a inner property?

Comment: The id field is already the value, I want the "Descricao" field to be valid, without having to join.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  mapping of NHibernate, which let's you map a property of another entity (related with the main one) as if it were part of it.
See here: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-join.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a proxy, you can get the identifier using `INHibernateProxy` reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10328489/1486443).

If you do not what to deal with proxies, just add an additional properties and map them, be sure to use `.Not.Insert().Not.Update()` to avoid mapping problems.

```
Map(m => m.DescricaoId)
    .Column("MPR_DS")
    .Not.Insert().Not.Update();

Map(m => m.AtivoId)
    .Column("MPR_ATIVO")
    .Not.Insert().Not.Update();
```